# Are SSD speeds reported in MB/s or MiB/s?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, ssd

MB = (1000)^2 bytes, MiB = (1024)^2 bytes. When benchmarking array read speed, my SSD is greatly underperforming if interpreting array sizes as Win 10 reports in "GB", which is actually (1024)^3 bytes, to be same as SSD's 1000MB:

[image]

Put differently, if SSD is advertised to read at 3400MB/s, is that actually 3242MB/s (`/=1.024^2`), or is the array 4.92GB?

---

Note: the SSDs in question are a [Sabrent Rocket NVMe PCIe M.2 2280](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07LGF54XR) and [Samsung 970 EVO Plus M.2 NVMe](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07M7Q21N7); either works.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, this is my exact question. [This](https://amzn.to/3uszcMt) SSD advertises 3400MB/s, and I ask whether they mean 3.4e6 B/s or (3.4 * 1024^2) B/s.

Comment: @Ramhound The SSD is rated 1TB in storage, which I confirmed to be 1e12 bytes, making it base 10, so if they are consistent, 3400MB/s means 3.4e6 B/s. Also "Bytes being 1024 bits" seems like a typo, unless we somehow speak of very different things.

Comment: Well I can't look at that Amazon link (it's blocked) a product name would have been better (contained in your question body).